# Write request content into CSV file python code

Tags: python, json, csv, python-requests, dashboard

I am fetching data from dashboard as json file using the following code:

```
ursl='https://xxxxxxxxx'
parameter = {
"access_token": 'ABCD',
                "startDate":"2021-05-23",
                "endDate":"2021-05-25",
                "userId":'ERTI'
}
r = requests.get(url = ursl, params = parameter)
```

then I save the content as json file then write it to a CSV file:

```
data=r.content
datajson=r.json() 
# opening the csv file in 'w+' mode
file = open('DaTA.csv', 'w+')
  
# writing the data into the file
with file:    
    write = csv.writer(file)
    write.writerow(datajson)
```

But I get all my data in one cell only.
This is a snapshot of the data:

```
{'date': {'_when': '2021-05-25', '_date': '2021-05-25T00:00:00.000Z'}, 'timeInterval': '1min', 'userId': '96K7D9', 'id': '60ac1401211c48001774aa3b', 'activities-heart': [{'customHeartRateZones': [], 'dateTime': '2021-05-25', 'heartRateZones': [{'caloriesOut': 993.8944, 'max': 115, 'min': 30, 'minutes': 1067, 'name': 'Out of Range'}, {'caloriesOut': 0, 'max': 142, 'min': 115, 'minutes': 0, 'name': 'Fat Burn'}, {'caloriesOut': 0, 'max': 175, 'min': 142, 'minutes': 0, 'name': 'Cardio'}, {'caloriesOut': 0, 'max': 220, 'min': 175, 'minutes': 0, 'name': 'Peak'}], 'value': '65.31'}], 'activities-heart-intraday': 
{'dataset': [{'time': '00:45:00', 'value': 62}, {'time': '00:46:00', 'value': 61}, {'time': '00:47:00', 'value': 61}, {'time': '00:48:00', 'value': 59}, {'time': '00:49:00', 'value': 59}
```

do you have any suggestion, as I want the data to be tow columns time and value, starting from the dataset word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if csv writer allows you to do what you need without looping through line by line.
Maybe use `pandas` instead?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(datajson['activities-heart-intraday']['dataset'])
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked, I just added [0] before ['activities-heart-intraday'].